# Where does gnome-session/gnome-shell store its configuration?

Tags: debian, gnome3, gnome-shell

Long story short; I have a debian system that's been running the `unstable` tree for over a decade straight (through fire, flames, and multiple hardware upgrades, but that aside). However, a while ago while Debian was transitioning to gnome3 and the `gnome-shell` desktop there were a couple of hitches in the process, and one or another of those left my regular user with an unusable configuration -- `gnome-shell` starts up and immediately crashes.

I tried setting up a completely blank new user, and everything runs fine for that one, so it's definitely an issue with a setting local to my main user somewhere... It's just that I have no idea where to start looking, and I don't want to blanket erase all configuration files because I kind of need the vast majority of them. So instead I'm looking to surgically remove all the configuration files and/or options that pertain to `gnome-shell` and let it rebuild them from scratch when I start it, then work from there.

**EDIT**: My bad, slight naming fail. The problem seems to be in `gnome-shell` rather than `gnome-session`.

Comment: [Similar question?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults). Should give some hint where to look at least.

Comment: Yes, but that'd nuke the settings for all sorts of *other* programs I am still using.

Comment: `gnome-shell` is new in Gnome3, making it hard to believe it's a problem with your old config. Try starting a separate xserver (as root) where gnome-shell (as your main-user) is the only client and see if gnome-shell will run if nothing else is running.

Comment: Like I said, debian went through a few iterations in `unstable` to get it right. I started working with gnome3 in sid when it first came out, and *somewhere* along the line something broke.

Comment: If gnome-shell starts up and immediately crashes, check for enabled gnome-shell add-ons.   Disable all add-ons to see if that fixes the crash.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know it's a gnome-session problem? It may just as well be program launched by gnome-session.

When it comes to configuraion, gnome is ... colourful. Configuration may be stored in

- ~/.gnomerc (file)
- ~/.gnome (dir)
- ~/.gnome2 (dir)
- ~/.local (dir)
- and of course in gconf, a.k.a. the gnome registry.

IIRC gnome-session doesn't do a whole lot. It starts the required components listed in gconf under /desktop/gnome/session (see /desktop/gnome/session/required_components for the programms that actually fulfill the requirements). After that it's rather passive.

To access this data you can either use a graphical user interface or `gconftool-2`. To browse through your configuration you could

```
gconftool-2 -a --all-dirs /desktop/gnome/session
gconftool-2 -a --all-dirs /desktop/gnome/session/required_components
```

gnome-sessions "config" is under`/apps/gnome-session`. What may also be interessting for you is `/apps/gnome_settings_daemon`, its subdirs and of course the `/apps` entries for all required components.

After that you need to scan through the directories. According to my experience most interessting options are in .gnomerc .gnome and .local. But I think .local is more of a recent thing in Gnome so your problem is probably not there.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder; looks like my actual problem is in `gnome-shell` rather than `gnome-session`. Question edited.

Comment: some your configuration files are missing.

Comment: please contribute by adding the missing locations, rather than just downvoting